# Aplication Deadlocks (ERROR 1213 (40001)) when running an alter table command

Tags: sql, deadlock, percona, mysql-5.6

When I'm running following alter table, the application which is still live is hitting deadlocks: ERROR 1213 (40001) at line 2: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `comm`
ADD COLUMN `thumb_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `search_index_version`,
ADD COLUMN `thumb_src_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
LOCK = NONE;
```

When I read the mysql 5.6 documentation it shouldn't lock, or am I wrong?

Version: Server version: 5.6.27-76.0-56-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel76.0, Revision 2a6d4e5, WSREP version 25.13, wsrep_25.13
Any pointers here?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe something else is accessing the table?

Comment: Sure, the app is still live and inserting data into the table, but it should be online DDL and shouldn't lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add column to a table that is beeing continuously used by an application, then you can meet deadlock - it means that your process is waiting for the other process to finish, and the other process is waiting for your process to finish. Usually every select/insert/update make some kind of lock on a table.

You can try turning off the application, make database changes and then turning it back on.

You can also try to lock the table only for you for a moment. I guess the syntax will be like that:

```
LOCK TABLE comm WRITE, comm READ;
ALTER TABLE `comm`
ADD COLUMN `thumb_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `search_index_version`,
ADD COLUMN `thumb_src_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '';
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Martinus, I get that but according to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html
Add a column 
In-Place? Yes*
Copies Table?  Yes*
Allows Concurrent DML? Yes*
Allows Concurrent Query?Yes

Comment: Maybe that will help? To use algorithm inplace you probably need to add algorithm=INPLACE to your query.
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72049/add-column-without-metadata-lock-in-mysql-5-6

`ALTER TABLE `comm`
ADD COLUMN `thumb_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `search_index_version`,
ADD COLUMN `thumb_src_url` varchar(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
algorithm=INPLACE,
LOCK = NONE;`

Comment: Same result: ERROR 1213 (40001) at line 2: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction